# UDP socket revfrom() return error

Tags: c++, udp

Purpose:
My code is to create a socket and receive a package from a client (this client broadcasts message every 500ms).
Phenomenon:
When the socket is created as a host socket, directly using revfrom() will return -1 from revfrom function. however, if I use sendto() function with any packet, then use revfrom() right away. This will help find the packet I need. googled it, it looks like a client socket,but I created it as a server socket.
below is my codes, please give any suggestion you have, appreciate it!
Code:

```
SOCKET s;
sockaddr_in addrDest;
sockaddr_in addrLocal;
int result;
char udp_buff[AMP_MAX_PACKET_SIZE];

WSADATA wsaData;
wchar_t msgbuf[100];

int addrDestSize = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);

// initialize winsock
result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (result != NO_ERROR) {
    wprintf(L"WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", result);
    //return 1;
}

// create the socket
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP); // UDP socket

u_long iMode = 1;
result = ioctlsocket(s, FIONBIO, &iMode);
if (result != NO_ERROR)
    printf("ioctlsocket failed with error: %ld\n", result);

addrLocal.sin_family = AF_INET;
addrLocal.sin_port = htons(16717);
addrLocal.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // zero-init sin_addr to tell it to use all available adapters on the local host

                                               // associate this socket with local UDP port 16717
result = bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&addrLocal, sizeof(addrLocal));

addrDest.sin_family = AF_INET;
addrDest.sin_port = htons(16717);
inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.99.255", &(addrDest.sin_addr));

uint8_t  node_address_temp[6] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };     //array 
std::vector<uint8_t> node_address(node_address_temp, node_address_temp + sizeof(node_address_temp) / sizeof(uint8_t));
//formatDataPack("MID", dataPack, node_address);
//SendCMDToGauge(&s, &dataPack, &addrDest);
result = sendto(s, " ", strlen(" ") + 1, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&addrDest, sizeof(addrDest));

result = -1;
while (result < 0 ) {
    result = recvfrom(s, (char*)&udp_buff, sizeof(udp_buff), 0, (SOCKADDR *)&addrDest, &addrDestSize);
    //result = recv(s, (char*)&udp_buff, sizeof(udp_buff), 0);
    swprintf(msgbuf, 100, L"Revfrom Result: %d\n", result);
    OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
    Sleep(500);
    if (result = 36)
        result = -1;
}
```

Comment: honestly, I am not sure how to define. In my application, my PC need to talk to a wifi device on the network, get its mac address from the packet the deice constantly sends out. and later will control this device by sending some formatted packs from PC. so from application, I guess it is a server?

Comment: I'm asking what you think the difference is between a "host socket", a "client socket", and a "server socket". You seem to be talking about two (or maybe three) different types of sockets with the type having some effect on the way your code behaves. I don't know what you mean by these terms. What is a "client socket" exactly?

Comment: forgive me if I used wrong terms. regardless of these terms, Im basically trying to understand how to use recfrom() to receive data from network.

Comment: I'm not concerned about what terms you use. I'm trying to understand what you're saying. As far as I know, a UDP socket is a UDP socket. You say something "looks like a client socket" and that something was "created .. as a server socket". I'm trying to figure out what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is expected. You have set the socket non-blocking. So if you call `recvfrom` and there is nothing to receive at that moment, it will return `-1` rather than blocking.

Comment: Im very new to socket, if you could provide some sample code for handling the case I would really appreciate.

Comment: There's nothing special you need to do. It's expected behavior. Your code already handles it, you just seem surprised that it's happening.

Comment: @Jacob Yeah.. if you wanted it to wait, why did you set it non-blocking?

Comment: I was surprised that I have to use sendto() function first and then I can receive the data on network since the device I want to receive data from keeps sends packet every 500ms.

Comment: @Jacob I am surprised too.  In fact, I would go as far as baffled.

Comment: @Jacob  ... or even  'are you sure, 'cos you should not need any sendto unless the protocol with the peer specifically needs it?'